# Pip installs within Docker container : Locally vs Remotely

Tags: python-3.x, docker, pip

I am working on several microservices written in Python 3. These microservices are deployed within a Docker container.

Within the Dockerfile I pip the necessary python modules needed to code's imports.

Here is the problem : on occasion pip fails with a 404 error, for example when pulling python-dateutil.

This problem is rare but annoying.

So, to avoid this,  I thought I would download necessary python modules, since current versions work and do not require updates, and make them part of the Docker bundling when making the container, and then pip install locally instead of installing from remotely.

Question : Is this approach recommendable?

The downside of this approach is if pip installs necessary modules locally, then these local modules will greatly increase the package size of a Docker container.

Comment: Can you come up with better question title? It has nothing to do about importing anything _locally_ or _remotely_ (whatever that means). You only asks about when to download package from pip - before creating image (and include it in image itself) or after running it.

Comment: I agree, renamed post.

Comment: What are you using as base image?

Comment: Dockerfile:  `FROM iron/python:3`